# Combining jQuery text() methods

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I have the following HTML snippet from my form. jQuery is checking to see which radio is checked, and then using the `text()` method to change the text in my element. I'm sure there is a better, cleaner way to write this. Can someone elaborate on how and why?

```
<p>
    <span class="input_small"><html:radio property="jobPosting.employmentTypeCode" value="RFT" styleId="fulltime" ><label for="fulltime">Full-Time</label></html:radio></span>
    <span class="input_small"><html:radio property="jobPosting.employmentTypeCode" value="RPT" styleId="parttime" ><label for="parttime">Part-Time</label></html:radio></span>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="responsibilities"><span class="job-time">*</span> position available with growing technology and government contracting firm. This person is responsible for:</label>
    <html:textarea property="jobPosting.requirements" rows="5" styleClass="input_xxxlarge" styleId="responsibilities" > </html:textarea>
</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fulltime').click(function() {
        if($('#fulltime').is(':checked')) {
            $('span.job-time').text('FT');
        }
    });
    $('#parttime').click(function(){
        if ($('#parttime').is(':checked')) {
            $('span.job-time').text('PT');
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: I would like to know how to accomplish this task with the least amount of jQuery code as possible.

Comment: If you are going to -1 please let him know why.  I personally think this is to localized so I voted to close.

Comment: I don't think it's too localized, but i do think it shows little to no research effort and doesn't quite fit the Q/A style of SO. There is no problem presented, the code isn't inefficient and it works. It may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com In what way do you want to make the code "better" or "clearner"? Both of those terms are subjective. Do you want to make it easier to maintain? make it execute faster? use less code?

Comment: Kevin, thanks for making the reference to code review. In the future, I will look there when I have a question similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('[id$=time]').change(function () {
    $('span.job-time').text($('#fulltime').is(':checked') ? 'FT' : 'PT');
});
```

- Call the `change` event in place of `click`, so
- `id$=time` is for the id which ends with `time` text
- If `fulltime` radio button is checked set the span text as `FT` else as `PT`.

Answer (score 2):

You can abbreviate it like this:

```
 $('#fulltime, #parttime').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('span.job-time').text( $(this).val().substring(1) );
    }
  });
```

Here I took chance your radio button values are `RFT` and `RPT` for fulltime and parttime respectively, so I take the last two characters to set the `span.job-time`.

Comment: I like it +1.  Didn't even see the values.

Comment: @Nelson, definitely like this approach. I checked Palash's because it was the least amount of code and that was my mission. Thanks for the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the selectors so there is only one click function(you can even shorten the if as @Palash Mondal mentioned):

```
$('#fulltime, #parttime').click(function() {
    if($('#fulltime').is(':checked')) {
        $('span.job-time').text('FT');
    }
    if ($('#parttime').is(':checked')) {
        $('span.job-time').text('PT');
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Good answer I used to build mine upon it.